# Implementing doubly linked list in C(deleteing a node at any position)

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I have this function that deletes a node at any position of the doubly linked list. It is working fine if you have only one node. I tried to insert 3 nodes, then delete the last one, it just freezes.

Here are the functions I used:

```
int getpos(char ln[20])
{
    int pos=1;

    temp3=h;
    if(temp3 == NULL)
        {
            printf("List empty");
            return;
        }

        while(temp3->next!=NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(temp3->lname,ln)==0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                pos++;
            }
        }

        return pos;
}
```

The function to get the position of the node to be deleted.

```
void del()
{
   int i = 1, pos=0;
    char ln[20];
    temp2 = h;


    printf("enter lname: ");
    gets(ln);

    pos=getpos(ln);

    if ((pos < 1) || (pos >= count + 1))
    {
        printf("\n Error : Position out of range to delete");
        return;
    }
    if (h == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Empty list no elements to delete");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while (i < pos)
        {
            temp2 = temp2->next;
            i++;
        }
        if (i == 1)
        {
            if (temp2->next == NULL)
            {
                printf("Node deleted from list");
                free(temp2);
                temp2 = h = NULL;
                return;
            }
        }
        if (temp2->next == NULL)
        {
            temp2->prev->next = NULL;
            free(temp2);
            printf("Node deleted from list");
            return;
        }
        temp2->next->prev = temp2->prev;
        if (i != 1)
            temp2->prev->next = temp2->next;    /* Might not need this statement if i == 1 check */
        if (i == 1)
            h = temp2->next;
        printf("\n Node deleted");
        free(temp2);
    }
    count--;

}
```

The function to delete the node.

Comment: Please read the guidelines. Before posting questions about code, first reduce it to the smallest but complete example.

Comment: You might like to try the approach(es) described here http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ to solve this issue yourself.

Comment: consider using a sentry node. have a look at http://pastebin.com/JAfq6ep1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `getpos`, you are not incrementing `temp3->next`, so the `while` loop is running forever.

By the way, a simple debugging attempt would have saved you the hassle of asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

you can write somthing like this:

```
void delete_node(Node* pNode)
{
 pNode->Data = pNode->Next->Data;
 pNode->Next->Next->Previous = pNode;
 Node* pTemp = pNode->Next;
 delete(pNode->Next);
 pNode->Next = pTemp;
}
```

This func. treats only nodes in the middle,
so just make sure to add edge cases - if the Node is first or last.